# how to use element from pop up window in parent page

Tags: javascript, html

This is parent html

```
<html>

<script language="javascript">

 function openwindow()

{

window.open("popups.html","_blank","height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no")

}

</script>

<body>

<form name=frm>

<input id=text1 type=text>

<input type=button onclick="javascript:openwindow()" value="Open window..">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

This is child html

```
 <html>

<script language="javascript">

function changeparent()

{

window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed..";

}

</script>

<body>

<form>

<input type=button onclick="javascript:changeparent()" value="Change opener's textbox's value..">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I need to access element from the pop up window(i.e child element). The code above is to access element from parent window. But even this doesn't work. Please help

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: @Quentin Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: your code is working...........

Comment: Text box value is not changing. Any other option how to access element from child page

Answer (score 0):

> `Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null"`

Security restrictions prevent webpages loaded from your hard disk from accessing other web pages loaded from your hard disk.

Install a web server and access them via http.

Answer (score -1):

put head tags around the script tags in the child, then it worked for me on Opera browser.

Comment: The start tag and end tag for the head element are optional in HTML. This will make no difference. The error message quoted in the comments makes it clear that the issue is a cross-origin permissions one.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't optional, I said i can open it fine with them but can't without them ?  So yes they do make a difference. I get no error or permissions trouble.Why the downvote for this, I'm only stating what worked for me and that may be a solution for the OP, Do you know what system he's got ? How do you know it doesn't work for him.